# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' | Installed pandas from git in Docker container

Tags: pandas, docker

This is not a duplicate of existing questions because:

1. I'm contributing to the pandas repository itself.
2. I've installed pandas using the git repo and not pip.
3. I've used a [Docker container as suggested by pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/development/contributing_environment.html) to create the development environment.
4. The pandas installation is successful & any file is not missing. I've manually verified that pandas._libs.interval is present.

When I tried to import from pandas, I'd get this error:

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/workspaces/pandas/pandas/conftest.py'.
../../../__init__.py:22: in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
../../../compat/__init__.py:15: in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
../../../compat/numpy/__init__.py:7: in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
../../../util/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
../../../util/_decorators.py:14: in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
../../../_libs/__init__.py:13: in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to rebuild the c extensions.

1. `python setup.py clean` (optional, use if 2. doesn't work)
2. `python setup.py build_ext -j 4`

Credits: @MarcoGorelli from the pandas community on Gitter.

More on why this solution works:

- I suspect that while docker was building the remote container, there were some issues due to an unreliable internet connection.
- As all modules were indeed present, one of the only possibilities would be that they couldn't be accessed by Python. The most plausible reason is an issue with the C compiler, something related to cython (interval is a.pyx file).

Also see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing_environment.html#creating-a-python-environment